# XMLAttribute is not working

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-attribute

I am Deserializing my xml into C# class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Applications>
    <Application Name = "name1" MakerCheckerType="Operational" SanctionCheckNeeded="N" PreExistCheckNeeded="N" >
    <InstrumentTypes>
        <InstrumentType  Version="1.0" PrimaryKeyExcel="Security Name" Name="Equity">
        </InstrumentType>
        <InstrumentType Name="Bond" Version="1.0" PrimaryKeyExcel="Security Name">
        </InstrumentType>
    </InstrumentTypes>
    <ProcessSteps>
        <ProcessStep VBAFunction="xyz" ExcelName="xyz" Name="Upload" />
        <ProcessStep Name ="Approve_Reject" VBAFunction="xyz" ExcelName="xyz"/>
    </ProcessSteps>
    </Application>
    <Application Name = "name2" MakerCheckerType="Real" SanctionCheckNeeded="Y" PreExistCheckNeeded="Y">
    <InstrumentTypes>
        <InstrumentType  Version="1.0" PrimaryKeyExcel="Security Name" Name="Equity">
        </InstrumentType>
        <InstrumentType Name="Bond" Version="1.0" PrimaryKeyExcel="Security Name">
        </InstrumentType>
    </InstrumentTypes>
    <ProcessSteps>
        <ProcessStep VBAFunction="xyz" ExcelName="xyz" Name="Upload" />
        <ProcessStep Name ="Approve_Reject" VBAFunction="xyz" ExcelName="xyz"/>
    </ProcessSteps>
    </Application>
</Applications>
```

classes are:

```
[XmlType("ProcessStep")]
public class IMAProcessStep
{
    private string name;
    private string vbaFunction;
    private string excelName;

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("VBAFunction")]
    public string VBAFunction
    {
        get { return vbaFunction; }
        set { vbaFunction = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("ExcelName")]
    public string ExcelName
    {
        get { return excelName; }
        set { excelName = value; }
    }
}

[XmlType("InstrumentType")]
public class IMAInstrumentType
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("Version")]
    public string Version
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute("PrimaryKeyExcel")]
    public string PrimaryKeyExcel
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[XmlType("Application")]
public class IMAApplication
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("MakerCheckerType")]
    public string MakerCheckerType { get; set; }

    public bool IsMakerCheckerType
    {
        get
        {
            if (MakerCheckerType == "Real")
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                MakerCheckerType = "Real";
            else
                MakerCheckerType = "Operational";
        }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("SanctionCheckNeeded")]
    public string SanctionCheckNeeded { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("PreExistCheckNeeded")]
    public string PreExistCheckNeeded { get; set; }

    public bool IsSanctionCheckNeeded
    {
        get
        {
            return SanctionCheckNeeded == "Y";
        }
        set
        {
            SanctionCheckNeeded = value ? "Y" : "N";
        }
    }

    public bool IsPreExistCheckNeeded
    {
        get
        {
            if (PreExistCheckNeeded == "Y")
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value)
                PreExistCheckNeeded = "Y";
            else
                PreExistCheckNeeded = "N";
        }
    }

    [XmlArray("ProcessSteps")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ProcessStep")]
    public List<IMAInstrumentType> SupportedInstrumentTypes { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("InstrumentTypes")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "InstrumentType")]
    public List<IMAProcessStep> ProcessSteps { get; set; }
}
```

Here How I am De serializing it...

```
List<IMAApplication> appConfig = null;

var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, configFilePath);

var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.ElementName = "Applications";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<IMAApplication>), xRoot);


using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
    appConfig = (List<IMAApplication>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);


return appConfig;
```

IMAApplication Deserialize successfully but processSteps and InstrumentTypes get only their Name attribute values. Rest of attributes are null.

Can anyone tell me what wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IMAApplications applications = Deserialize(FILENAME);
        }

        static IMAApplications Deserialize(string configFilePath)
        {
            IMAApplications appConfig = null;

            var path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, configFilePath);

            var xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
            xRoot.ElementName = "Applications";
            xRoot.IsNullable = true;
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IMAApplications), xRoot);


            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
                appConfig = (IMAApplications)serializer.Deserialize(stream);


            return appConfig;
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("ProcessStep")]
    public class IMAProcessStep
    {
        private string name;
        private string vbaFunction;
        private string excelName;

        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        [XmlAttribute("VBAFunction")]
        public string VBAFunction
        {
            get { return vbaFunction; }
            set { vbaFunction = value; }
        }

        [XmlAttribute("ExcelName")]
        public string ExcelName
        {
            get { return excelName; }
            set { excelName = value; }
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("InstrumentType")]
    public class IMAInstrumentType
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlAttribute("Version")]
        public string Version
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        [XmlAttribute("PrimaryKeyExcel")]
        public string PrimaryKeyExcel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("Applications")]
    public class IMAApplications
    {
        [XmlElement("Application")]
        public List<IMAApplication> applications { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Application")]
    public class IMAApplication
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("MakerCheckerType")]
        public string MakerCheckerType { get; set; }

        public bool IsMakerCheckerType
        {
            get
            {
                if (MakerCheckerType == "Real")
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value)
                    MakerCheckerType = "Real";
                else
                    MakerCheckerType = "Operational";
            }
        }

        [XmlAttribute("SanctionCheckNeeded")]
        public string SanctionCheckNeeded { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("PreExistCheckNeeded")]
        public string PreExistCheckNeeded { get; set; }

        public bool IsSanctionCheckNeeded
        {
            get
            {
                return SanctionCheckNeeded == "Y";
            }
            set
            {
                SanctionCheckNeeded = value ? "Y" : "N";
            }
        }
        public bool IsPreExistCheckNeeded
        {
            get
            {
                if (PreExistCheckNeeded == "Y")
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value)
                    PreExistCheckNeeded = "Y";
                else
                    PreExistCheckNeeded = "N";
            }
        }


    [XmlArray("InstrumentTypes")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "InstrumentType")]
    public List<IMAInstrumentType> SupportedInstrumentTypes { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ProcessSteps")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "ProcessStep")]
    public List<IMAProcessStep> ProcessSteps { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this code and result is same as mine... in ProcessStep only Name attribute is populating, not other attributes

Comment: The last 6 lines of code you have ProcessSteps <IMAInstruments> and InstrumentTypes <IMAProcessStep> switched.

Comment: I found the issue when I noticed Equity was in Process instead of Instruments.

Comment: thanks for your help... I was stuck in this issue since more than 2 hours